# Why is russian beta testing software on my Mac?

Tags: macos, utilities

Yesterday I discovered that there is a piece of software called "Ассистент обратной связи" in the `/System/Library/CoreServices/Applications` Directory of my Mac (OS X Mavericks). What's the deal with this application? Is is legit? Why does it have a Russian title?

Comment: Hello, welcome to Ask Different. I checked what "Ассистент обратной связи" means at translate.google.com, it is: Feedback Assistant. What is the installation date of that software? Have you installed a beta macOS version around that date?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like `Feedback Assistant.app`. Maybe it's missing the en translations. You can check if that really is the correct app in Terminal with:

```
ls /System/Library/CoreServices/Applications
```

The output will reveal the real (not translated) applications names.

The `Ассистент обратной связи` string could be found using:

```
plutil -p Feedback\ Assistant.app/Contents/Resources/ru.lproj/InfoPlist.strings
```

The output:

> `{
>     "CFBundleDisplayName" => "Ассистент обратной связи"
>     "CFBundleName" => "Ассистент обратной связи"
>   }`

To make sure, the app is really from Apple you can run

```
codesign -d -vvv Feedback\ Assistant.app
```

and look for `Authority=Apple Code Signing Certification Authority`.

Comment: Thanks! Indeed, it appears to be the Feedback Assistant. Weird ...

Comment: If you are on 10.9, the easiest fix to this missing language components of a system application is to just download 10.9.5 Combo and run that. It will most likely fix the problem.

Comment: Did the additional steps, it appears to be legit. @l008com I'm running 10.9.5 if this is what you mean ... This is the first time I've encountered such a translation "bug"

Comment: What I'm saying is re-run the 10.9.5 Combo installer.